# Google sheet reset cell values on page load or refresh

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Is there a way to set certain cells to their "default" values when sharing with the public?

I have a button that will do it, but I'd like for anonymous users to just get the values to reset when they load the page (or refresh).

```
function reset_defaults() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  sheet.getRange('C4').setValue('5000');
    sheet.getRange('C5').setValue('3 Years');
  sheet.getRange('C6').setValue('3 Years');
  sheet.getRange('C7').setValue('=TREND(Pricing!E7:E16,Pricing!D7:D16,C4)/C4');
  sheet.getRange('C8').setValue('100');
  sheet.getRange('C9').setValue('2000');


}
```

Comment: Try [onOpen()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#open)

Comment: You can't just clear one user's sheet. The sheet is on Google servers. If you clear for one, you clear for all.